# How to append a class when hovered on a span

Tags: jquery

**My HTML**

```
<span class="lead_button">
  <img class="NFButtonLeft" src="/templates/web/images/0.png">
  <button type="submit" class="NFButton" id="cf_ce-submit-button">Send</button>
  <img src="/templates/web/images/0.png" class="NFButtonRight">
</span>
```

What I am trying to do is, when some one `hover` over the `span` I want to add appednd a class called `NFh` to the `images` and `button` . So the final output will look like this

```
<span class="lead_button">
  <img class="NFButtonLeft NFh" src="/templates/web/images/0.png">
  <button type="submit" class="NFButton NFh" id="cf_ce-submit-button">Send</button>
  <img src="/templates/web/images/0.png" class="NFButtonRight NFh">
</span>
```

How can I achieve this with jQuery? Thanks heaps.

Comment: I tried addClass, but Im thinking how to add the class to the objects inside the span?

Comment: @nasty show us how you tried??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly what you need.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.lead_button').hover(function(){
        $(this).children().each(function(){
            $(this).addClass("NFh");

        });
    });
    $('.lead_button').mouseout(function(){
        $(this).children().each(function(){
            $(this).removeClass("NFh");

        });
    });
});
</script>
<span class="lead_button">
    <img class="NFButtonLeft" src="/templates/web/images/0.png">
    <button type="submit" class="NFButton" id="cf_ce-submit-button">Send</button>
    <img src="/templates/web/images/0.png" class="NFButtonRight">
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('span.lead_button').hover(function() {
        $(this).find('img, button').removeClass('NFH').addClass('NFH');
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("span").hover(function() {
    $(this).children().addClass("NFh");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.lead_button').hover(
    // Event on Mouse Hover
    function(){
       $(this).find('img').addClass('NFh');
       $(this).find('#cf_ce-submit-button').addClass('NFh');
    }, 
   // Event on Mouse Out
   //function(){
      // Event goes here
   //}
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.find()` function to capture the button and image elements inside the span.

```
$('span.lead_button').hover(function(){  
      $(this).find('img, button').addClass('NFH'); 
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/KYMrA/)**